# Appending Script to DOM without JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

> The only way to fix it was using google chrome/IE10+ Just can't make it work on IE8.

I'm trying to append some Script to my web page, but i don't want to use any Jquery.

This DOES work, but it make use of jquery on the 3rd line.

```
var element = document.getElementById("contentSCRIPT");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);            // this removes the div and all the javascript inside it
    $('<div id="contentSCRIPT"></div>').appendTo(document.getElementById("main")); // this adds again the content to the page
    $('<script>' + document.getElementById("textSCRIPT").value + ' ;</' + 'script>').appendTo(document.getElementById("contentSCRIPT"));       // in here i try to add the javascript code back to the content.
```

I tryied:

```
var content = document.createTextNode('<div id="contentSCRIPT"></div>');
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(content);
```

but it adds my script (content) as HTML not code.

any solutions?
Thanks!

Edit:

I have to create the contentScript cuz i want to delete the script from the page and add another multiple times.

I tryied

```
var contentScript = document.createElement("script");
    contentScript.setAttribute("id", "contentSCRIPT");
    document.getElementById('contentSCRIPT').innerHTML = document.getElementById('textoSCRIPT').value;
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(contentScript);
```

But again, this adds the code as an HTML (shows like a label on the page) and don't add to the DOM.

Comment: What script are you trying to add to the page? Is it text already present on the page, or are you trying to load/import an external file's script?

Comment: @Dom: can I ask what you think he's currently *trying* to use?

Comment: I am using Javascript... I already have some text on the page. the textSCRIPT element is a textarea input.

Comment: @user3174789 After your edit it looks like you've a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/202792) here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('<div id="contentSCRIPT"></div>')` can be written as follows in javascript:

```
var contentScript = document.createElement("div");
contentScript.setAttribute("id", "contentSCRIPT");
```

To do jQuery's `appendTo`, you want instead to `appendChild` on the parent:

```
document.getElementById("main").appendChild(contentScript);
```

Similarly, for the fourth line:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.innerHTML = document.getElementById('textSCRIPT').value;
contentScript.appendChild(script);
```

**EDIT**

Based on your edited information, you *don't* need to create the div to hold the contentScript.  Simply put an id on the script instead:

```
var contentScript = document.createElement("script");
contentScript.setAttribute("id", "contentSCRIPT");
contentScript.innerHTML = document.getElementById('textSCRIPT').value;
document.getElementById("main").appendChild(contentScript);
```

Comment: Already tryied, Does the same as i did, it adds as a HTML on the page not as Script

Comment: @user3174789 Sorry, I missed the fourth line, but have edited it in.  The reason it's adding as HTML is because I added it directly to the div, instead of adding it to a script tag added to the div.  This version should be better

Comment: @user3174789 My code before the edit should serve you well, but you may want to look at my edit as well, and see if that works for you.

Comment: it gives an error on the line contentScript.innerHTML = document.getElementById('textSCRIPT').value;
Tryied to change the line to contentScript.innerHTML = "alert('test');"; but still gives an error

Comment: The element can't be found. I think adding an ID after creating it doesn't work?

Comment: @DanielBoldrin `textSCRIPT` is a different element, that all of your code has been referencing.  The issue isn't with `contentSCRIPT`, which is the id that I set.  setting `contentScript.innerHTML = "alert('test');"` should have properly set the innerHTML of the script variable.  Doing exactly that works perfectly in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BjbAd/).

Comment: when i use contentScript.innerHTML it shows a label on my page instead of alerting... Can it be anything?

Comment: @DanielBoldrin Look at the link I sent in my previous comment.  If it's appearing as a label, you're setting the innerHTML of a div, not a script tag.

Comment: your link also does not work.. Im using IE 7/8 is that the problem?

Comment: @DanielBoldrin That is almost certainly the problem.  There is a lot that IE7/8 doesn't implement, though in this case I don't know which command it doesn't like.  It works in IE 11.  :-)  The best I can suggest is you post the code from the fiddle in another question and ask why it's failing in IE 7/8.

Comment: OK! Thank you very much! For now i'll just use google chrome for tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a script element and append it to the document:

```
var script = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script'));
script.text = '/* CODE */';
```

As a response to your edit: You can remove a script element from the DOM, but you can't [remove the script itself](http://jsfiddle.net/b46KD/1/).

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b46KD/).

Comment: With enough knowledge of the script, it should be possible to `delete` the objects the script created, particularly if it's good at not polluting the global namespace.  But of course, that is another step beyond removing the element.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Yes, it is possible, but the final result depends on the code. Also some objects, like functions for timers can't be deleted, if a timer is running when trying to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
var contentScript = document.createElement("div");

contentScript.setAttribute("id", "contentSCRIPT");
script.innerHTML = document.getElementById('textSCRIPT').value;
contentScript.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a script tag programatically by simply adding the `script` tag:

```
var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(document.createElement("script"));

scriptTag.innerHTML = document.getElementById("textSCRIPT").value;
```

Change "head" to "body" if you want to add the script to the body.